# How can memoized functions be tested?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-decorators

I have a simple memoizer which I'm using to save some time around expensive network calls. Roughly, my code looks like this:

```
# mem.py
import functools
import time


def memoize(fn):
    """
    Decorate a function so that it results are cached in memory.

    >>> import random
    >>> random.seed(0)
    >>> f = lambda x: random.randint(0, 10)
    >>> [f(1) for _ in range(10)]
    [9, 8, 4, 2, 5, 4, 8, 3, 5, 6]
    >>> [f(2) for _ in range(10)]
    [9, 5, 3, 8, 6, 2, 10, 10, 8, 9]
    >>> g = memoize(f)
    >>> [g(1) for _ in range(10)]
    [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
    >>> [g(2) for _ in range(10)]
    [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]
    """
    cache = {}

    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        key = args, tuple(sorted(kwargs))
        try:
            return cache[key]
        except KeyError:
            cache[key] = fn(*args, **kwargs)
            return cache[key]
    return wrapped


def network_call(user_id):
    time.sleep(1)
    return 1


@memoize
def search(user_id):
    response = network_call(user_id)
    # do stuff to response
    return response
```

And I have tests for this code, where I mock out different return values of `network_call()` to make sure some modifications I do in `search()` work as expected.

```
import mock

import mem


@mock.patch('mem.network_call')
def test_search(mock_network_call):
    mock_network_call.return_value = 2
    assert mem.search(1) == 2


@mock.patch('mem.network_call')
def test_search_2(mock_network_call):
    mock_network_call.return_value = 3
    assert mem.search(1) == 3
```

However, when I run these tests, I get a failure because `search()` returns a cached result.

```
CAESAR-BAUTISTA:~ caesarbautista$ py.test test_mem.py
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.8 -- py-1.4.26 -- pytest-2.6.4
collected 2 items

test_mem.py .F

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
________________________________ test_search_2 _________________________________

args = (<MagicMock name='network_call' id='4438999312'>,), keywargs = {}
extra_args = [<MagicMock name='network_call' id='4438999312'>]
entered_patchers = [<mock._patch object at 0x108913dd0>]
exc_info = (<class '_pytest.assertion.reinterpret.AssertionError'>, AssertionError(u'assert 2 == 3\n +  where 2 = <function search at 0x10893f848>(1)\n +    where <function search at 0x10893f848> = mem.search',), <traceback object at 0x1089502d8>)
patching = <mock._patch object at 0x108913dd0>
arg = <MagicMock name='network_call' id='4438999312'>

    @wraps(func)
    def patched(*args, **keywargs):
        # don't use a with here (backwards compatability with Python 2.4)
        extra_args = []
        entered_patchers = []

        # can't use try...except...finally because of Python 2.4
        # compatibility
        exc_info = tuple()
        try:
            try:
                for patching in patched.patchings:
                    arg = patching.__enter__()
                    entered_patchers.append(patching)
                    if patching.attribute_name is not None:
                        keywargs.update(arg)
                    elif patching.new is DEFAULT:
                        extra_args.append(arg)

                args += tuple(extra_args)
>               return func(*args, **keywargs)

/opt/boxen/homebrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.py:1201:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

mock_network_call = <MagicMock name='network_call' id='4438999312'>

    @mock.patch('mem.network_call')
    def test_search_2(mock_network_call):
        mock_network_call.return_value = 3
>       assert mem.search(1) == 3
E       assert 2 == 3
E        +  where 2 = <function search at 0x10893f848>(1)
E        +    where <function search at 0x10893f848> = mem.search

test_mem.py:15: AssertionError
====================== 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.03 seconds ======================
```

Is there a way to test memoized functions? I've considered some alternatives but they each have drawbacks.

One solution is to mock `memoize()`. I am reluctant to do this because it leaks implementation details to the tests. Theoretically, I should be able to memoize and unmemoize functions without the rest of the system, including tests, noticing from a functional standpoint.

Another solution is to rewrite the code to expose the decorated function. That is, I could do something like this:

```
def _search(user_id):
    return network_call(user_id)
search = memoize(_search)
```

However, this runs into the same problems as above, although it's arguably worse because it will not work for recursive functions.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Why do you have two tests testing for different return values?  If it is okay for your memoized function to return a "stale" value (not the same as the live value from the network), then you shouldn't test for two values.  If it is not okay, then you need to make your memoization more sophisticated so that you can somehow invalidate the cache when necessary.  There's no use in memoizing if you don't have a way to know when it's okay to use the memoized value vs. getting the real value.

Comment: I don't understand why your proposed solution wouldn't work. Couldn't you just use `_search` in your tests? My assumption is that you want to test the behavior of `_search` when the network call returns various values, and aren't interested in the memoization.

Comment: Hm, having trouble following you.

The tests have different return values to simulate `network_call()` whose return values may be different for the same parameters (i.e. depending on the value on a server). They are supposed to be independent, so there should not be a need to invalidate the cache.

Comment: @Asad, Yes I could use `_search`, but as I mentioned it leaks implementation details to the tests and will not work if `_search` is recursive.

Comment: Okay, so imagine the following real world scenario. You call the memoized `search` function with the input `1`, it returns 1 (because that's how the server currently behaves). Let's say in the future the server state changes so it returns something else when you pass in `1`. Is the expected behavior for the memoized `search` function to always return `1`?

Comment: @CeasarBautista: If an actual user of your code called `mem.search(1)` under conditions where `network_call` returned 2, and then subsequently called `mem.search(1)` under conditions where `network_call` returned 3, what should the result be?  If you want the calls to be independent, you need to invalidate the cache.  If you never invalidate the cache, changes in the behavior of `network_call` will never affect later calls to `mem.search` (with the same arguments).

Comment: @Asad and @BrenBarn, you are both right, the results should be different. However, 1) I don't expect the server to change in between invocations. In my app I have two functions which both use `search` slightly differently which I call in quick succession. I also don't want to pass around the result, because the result is an implementation detail of those two functions, and not essential to them. And 2) even if (1) were false, it's unclear how to test this.

Comment: @CeasarBautista The scenario you're currently testing only arises if the server changes in between invocations.

Comment: Or more specifically, if the server's response for the input 1 changes between invocations.

Comment: @Asad, that's not true. A test that wanted to check for that would make two calls to `search()` in the same body. Unit tests are supposed to be isolated.

Comment: @CeasarBautista That's only true for unit tests that do not affect the environment state. This isn't the case with your unit tests (the wrapper function's cache is mutated). If you want your unit tests to be isolated, you need to run a teardown and setup between them. In this case this would involve recreating the search function from its definition and the decorator or clearing the memoization cache in some other way.

Comment: @CeasarBautista: They can't isolate global state, which is effectively what your memoization is.  If one test sets a global variable `blah = 1`, other tests will see that too.  Likewise memoized values are stored globally (in the closure of the memoized function).  If you want the memoization to happen on some non-global level, you need to make `search` a non-global function (e.g., a method of some class).  Or, again, you can provide a "manual override" of some sort that invalidates the cache.

Comment: @Asad and @BrenBarn, that's more clear now. The closure had me thrown off. But to answer your question, @BrenBarn, I am not trying to test memoization here. Assume `search` was not memoized-- the tests would still make sense. I want to test what happens when the servers returns different responses.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is it really desirable for your memoization to be defined at the function level?

This effectively makes the memoized data a *global variable* (just like the function, whose scope it shares).

Incidentally, that's why you're having difficulty testing it!

So, how about wrapping this into an object?

```
import functools
import time

def memoize(meth):
    @functools.wraps(meth)
    def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # Prepare and get reference to cache
        attr = "_memo_{0}".format(meth.__name__)
        if not hasattr(self, attr):
            setattr(self, attr, {})
        cache = getattr(self, attr)

        # Actual caching
        key = args, tuple(sorted(kwargs))
        try:
            return cache[key]
        except KeyError:
            cache[key] = meth(self, *args, **kwargs)
            return cache[key]

    return wrapped

def network_call(user_id):
    print "Was called with: %s" % user_id
    return 1

class NetworkEngine(object):

    @memoize
    def search(self, user_id):
        return network_call(user_id)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    e = NetworkEngine()
    for v in [1,1,2]:
        e.search(v)
    NetworkEngine().search(1)
```

Yields:

```
Was called with: 1
Was called with: 2
Was called with: 1
```

In other words, each instance of `NetworkEngine` gets its own cache. Just reuse the same one to share a cache, or instantiate a new one to get a new cache.

---

In your test code, you'd use:

```
@mock.patch('mem.network_call')
def test_search(mock_network_call):
    mock_network_call.return_value = 2
    assert mem.NetworkEngine().search(1) == 2
```

Comment: +1 for a great answer, but it might be a bit quicker to understand this if you used the OP's original code.

Answer (score 0):

You should test each concern separately:

You have shown `memoize`, and I assume you have tested that.

You seem to have `network_call`, so you should test that in isolation, not memoized.

Now you want to combine the two, but presumably this will be for the benefit of other code to avoid lengthy network latency. However, if you want to test this other code then it should not even make 1 network call, so you may have to supply a function name as a parameter.